# Error "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder'" when try to se spark on Intelli 2021.2.3 on Windows 11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, sbt

I'm trying to run the following test at scale:

```
  test("RawData read") {
    val typp = ""
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate()
    val actual = new DataReader(spark, typp).readRawData("./src/test/resources/input/parquet/part-00000-512bb01c-ef7a-4760-bfe9-905f504e4840.c000.snappy.parquet")
    actual.coalesce(1).limit(100).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("./src/test/resources/output/")

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val expected: Dataset[RawData] = spark
      .read
      .parquet("./src/test/resources/output/")
      .map(row => RawData(
        row.getString(0),
        row.getDouble(1),
        row.getInt(2),
        row.getString(3),
        row.getDouble(4),
        row.getLong(5),
        row.getString(6)
      ))

    assert(actual.limit(100).collectAsList() === expected.collectAsList())
  }
```

The error that I recive is this:

> Error while instantiating
> 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating
> 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$3.apply(SparkSession.scala:902)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$3.apply(SparkSession.scala:902)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:902)
> at
> eu.man.bigdata.commons.importer.DataReaderTest$$anonfun$2.apply(DataReaderTest.scala:23)
> at
> eu.man.bigdata.commons.importer.DataReaderTest$$anonfun$2.apply(DataReaderTest.scala:21)
> at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)  at
> org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)   at
> org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)     at
> org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)     at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:186)  at
> org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)    at
> org.scalatest.FunSuite.withFixture(FunSuite.scala:1560)   at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:183)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:196)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:196)
> at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)  at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTest(FunSuiteLike.scala:196)  at
> eu.man.bigdata.commons.importer.DataReaderTest.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterEach$$super$runTest(DataReaderTest.scala:13)
> at
> org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterEach$class.runTest(BeforeAndAfterEach.scala:221)
> at
> eu.man.bigdata.commons.importer.DataReaderTest.runTest(DataReaderTest.scala:13)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:229)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:229)
> at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:396)
> at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)    at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
> at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)     at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTests(FunSuiteLike.scala:229)     at
> org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTests(FunSuite.scala:1560)  at
> org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1147)   at
> org.scalatest.FunSuite.org$scalatest$FunSuiteLike$$super$run(FunSuite.scala:1560)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:233)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:233)
> at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)  at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.run(FunSuiteLike.scala:233)  at
> eu.man.bigdata.commons.importer.DataReaderTest.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(DataReaderTest.scala:13)
> at
> org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
> at
> org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
> at
> eu.man.bigdata.commons.importer.DataReaderTest.run(DataReaderTest.scala:13)
> at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)    at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1346)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1340)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1340)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1011)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1010)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
> at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)    at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)  at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:38)
> at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:25)
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root
> scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions
> are: rw-rw-rw-;   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
> ... 63 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS
> should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-    at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
> ... 72 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch
> dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are:
> rw-rw-rw-     at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
> ... 86 more

I'm using sbt version 1.0.3, I have tried many of the solutions posed in the various questions related to this problem but nothing has worked